# Clone git repository from github without full URL

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to clone a git repository from github without the full URL?

For example:
When I have to run this: `git clone https://github.com/foo/bar.git`
I want enter this: `git clone foo/bar`

I saw a solution on the internet, but I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the [`hub`](https://github.com/github/hub) tool, then make `git` a shell alias for `hub`.

Answer (score 5):

If you only wanted to do this using `git` you can edit your `.gitconfig` file by adding a url alias like so:

```
[url "<actual url base>"]
    insteadOf = <other url base>
```

For example with this:

```
[url "https://github.com/"]
    insteadOf = gh:
```

Then you could do:

```
 git clone gh:foo/bar.git
```

Its not exacally what you asked for but is an alternative to having to install another command line tool.

Thanks to the [git docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) and [Stefan Majewsky](http://majewsky.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/tip-of-the-day-dont-remember-git-clone-urls/)